# How remove the extra space between two records of Jasper Table?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.1.1 And I am inserting data which is more than one page in table records.
In this scenario, first page of table component shows blank record and actual data will be started from next page.

Here is screenshot of Generated PDF Template for reference.

[image]

How can I remove this blank space of first page.

The JRXML file can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/86kr165kypryxj6/CreditNote.jrxml?dl=0).

Comment: You probably should show the jrxml...

Comment: Many Thanks mkl, for adding my image in question. Im new user of stackoverflow and couldn't know how to attach .jrxml file into questions.
Could you please guide me for same?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow attaching anything but images directly. It is necessary, therefore, to publish other kinds of attachment elsewhere and then post the link here. Please don't use a file sharing service that drowns a downloader in ads. Instead use something like public shares on dropbox, google drive, or some similar service.

Comment: Hi mkl,
Please find the below link for jrxml.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/86kr165kypryxj6/CreditNote.jrxml?dl=0

Comment: At first glance I cannot tell how to change this behavior. But I'm not really a JR pro. Thus, I edited the link into your question hoping some pro will see it.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is managed by the `splitType` attribute of the band (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/SplitTypeEnum.html). In your case, I think, `IMMEDIATE` will work the best. If it does not, you will have to play with your band height while having `splitType=STRETCH`

Comment: Many Thanks, Mr Robert. But above mentioned solution didn't solve the problem i am facing. have applied different splitType to Detail Band, but the data displayed in product table is print by using Table Component so there is no  change in output which is described in Above Question.